# How to determine that a set of equations has a solution or infinite many solution or no solution?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-software

I have a set of polynomials (the variables are $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,e_1,f_1,g_1,h_1,i_1,j_1$, the polynomials are $L_i$, $i=1,\ldots,20$):
$$
aa_1=0 ; [L_1]\\
e a_1 + b e_1=0; [L_2]\\
b b_1=0; [L_{3}]\\
h a_1 + c h_1 + f e_1=0; [L_{4}]\\
f b_1 + c f_1=0; [L_{5}]\\
c c_1=0; [L_{6}]\\
j a_1 + d j_1 + i e_1 + g h_1=0; [L_{7}]\\
i b_1 + d i_1 + g f_1=0; [L_{8}]\\
g c_1 + d g_1=0; [L_{9}]\\
d d_1=0; [L_{10}]\\
j_1=0; [L_{11}]\\
i_1=0; [L_{12}]\\
g_1=0; [L_{13}]\\
d_1=0; [L_{14}]\\
b c j - b g h - c e i + e f g=0; [L_{15}]\\
h i-f j=0; [L_{16}]\\
j=0; [L_{17}]\\
h_1 i_1-f_1 j_1=0; [L_{18}]\\
b_1 c_1 j_1 - b_1 g_1 h_1 - c_1 e_1 i_1 + e_1 f_1 g_1=0; [l_{19}]\\
j a_1 c_1 i_1 - i b_1 c_1 j_1 - j a_1 f_1 g_1 + i b_1 g_1 h_1 + i c_1 e_1 i_1 - i e_1 f_1 g_1=0; [L_{20}]
$$

I would like to know that the set of equations: $L_i$, $i=1,\ldots,20$,  has a solution or infinite many solution or no solution. Are there some software can do this job? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maple-> solve could be a start. It does not always give the correct answer however, so you need to check.

Comment: Try editing your question so it will be readable by humans. For a start, put every equation in its own row. Also, enclose the equations with dollar signs and add indices by using the `_` symbol, so you will have $a_1$ (written as `$a_1$`) instead of a1

Comment: This post is unreadable.

Comment: @LJR I'm sorry, but you are wrong. This is a site dedicated to mathematitians, not programmers. Readability has an advantage over copy pasting into software. Also, the post is still not readable. I have no idea what the polynomials are and what the variables are.

Comment: I have formatted the equations to make it clear there are polynomials, though it's confusing that you state there are only the twelve variables $a,b,c,d,e,f,a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,e_1,f_1$.  What are we to make of $g,h,i,j,g_1,h_1,i_1,j_1$?  Are they known values?  Equations $L_{11},L_{17}$ require $j,j_1=0$, so these cannot hold unless that happens to be true.  If it is true, those terms containing factors of $j,j_1$ can be eliminated, etc.

Comment: @hardmath, sorry, $g,h,i,j,g_1,h_1,i_1,j_1$ are also variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the letters denoted indeterminates, then you can easily feed the system into Macaulay2, for example.

It will then turn out that the ideal generated by the polynomials $f_i$ is $9$-dimensional, so there are certainly many (possibly complex) solutions. In particular, $0$ is in the solution set, so you always have at least one real solution.

Comment: thank you very much. I think the ideal generated by the polynomials $l_i, i=1,\ldots,20$, is 20-dimensional. I checked using Macaulay2 that these polynomials are independent. But I would like to know how to use Macaulay2 or other software to determine directly that the set of equations has a solution or infinitely many solution or no solution. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @LJR Hi. I also did this in M2, and then I got out 9. How did you implement it? Since the dimension is $9$, of course it has infinitely many complex solutions.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot putting $g,h,i,j,g_1,h_1,i_1,j_1$ as variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably doable without any software. Start by substituting the variables that you know are $0$. Then you've also got a bunch of equations of the form $xy = 0$; make case distinctions $x = 0$, $y = 0$ and see what you wind up with. It wouldn't surprise me if what remains (in each of the many cases) is easy enough to solve.